# How to allow file upload in Microsoft Dynamics CRM forms?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

Under Project service:

[image: CRM project service]

And under project template:

[image: project template]

There is a possibility of customizing forms in [Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm.aspx), through Customize entity:

[image: customize entity]

Also, seems like we can add a new field as well:

[image: Add a new field]

to forms:

[image: Dynamics CRM form]

I see that there is no file field in the forms:

[image: data types in Dynamics CRM form]

> Is there a way to allow file upload in Microsoft Dynamics CRM forms?

Maybe programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Notes enabled on the entity, you can upload files via the notes component on the form.

To enable it, go to the entity customization and check the Notes box, and then add notes to your entity form.
Now you can upload files on the entity form by adding a new note on the record, through the newly added Notes component.

Picture guide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwjrd.jpg

An alternative is using something like SharePoint instead to host your files, and using the standard CRM/SharePoint integration to access them in CRM. That way you won't use up all your expensive CRM storage with files.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I needed

Comment: Now this Notes 'thingy' is called Timeline.. just in case one can not find it.

Answer (score 2):

The standard option for doing a file upload is creating a note (entity `annotation`) which can have a file attached to it.

Alternatively you can create a custom HTML web resource handling the upload for you. This requires common HTML/Javascript techniques, as discussed elsewhere on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, doing what Henk van Boeijen mentioned (custom HTML/Js) will be more appealing in terms of UI. 
You just need to enable notes, and after that, use REST endpoint. Example is here: http://scaleablesolutions.com/upload-notes-attachments-using-javascript-and-rest/